# VSTO - Abort opening an Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vsto

I have an Excel 2016 workbook that does some validation on opening. I'm using VSTO, here's a snippet of the code:

```
Private Sub ThisWorkbook_Open() Handles Me.Open
    Try
        If (DoNotOpen()) Then
            Me.Close() 'this throws a System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
...
```

The exception that occurs cannot be swallowed, as it will be re-thrown, as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2005/07/22/442866.aspx#comments). I understand why the exception is thrown (because closing the workbook before finishing opening it). I'm looking for the best way to abort opening (I found that I could altogether close Excel programmatically, by executing Me.Application.Quit, but I'm not entirely comfortably doing so because the code does not exit properly). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to close the (half) opened workbook think about working the other way around. Only activate (add) the event handler when you think it should be active to only open the proper workbooks.

There are other known alternatives where the open event is in place, some very tricky, like activating a Timer when DoNotOpen() is in place, hiding the opened workbook and a bit later when the timer triggered closing the opened workbook or just open the workbook set invisible and close when Excel closes without saving the hidden workbooks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Is there an event that happens before Open() that I can latch on? Your first suggestion is to do the DoNotOpenCall() before the workbook opens. I could not find a way to do so.  I have also tried the timer suggestion: I added a DontOpen boolean property to ThisWorkbook, setting it on opening the workbook, then calling a StartTimer function that I added in a new module. The timer function async awaits, then reads DontOpen value and calls Close() if True. Same error, still...

Comment: There sadly is no WorkbookBeforeOpen (cf WorkbookBeforeClose) event (You can check by going into the Object Browser in VBA, select the Application Object and right click in the Members of Application list and select Group Members. Now all events are together in the list at the bottom). Here is one of the examples with a delayed close timer: http://excelribbon.tips.net/T008192_Forcing_a_Workbook_to_Close_after_Inactivity.html I think you need to play a bit with the time to use on the timer to make it fit your need.

Comment: Thank you again. The timer example you are quoting requires the workbook be macro-enabled. I can't enable macros, for security reasons imposed by the customer. I am very close to conclude that there is no known way of closing a workbook from managed code without the ThreadAbortException being thrown. That's unfortunate, but not a deal breaker (showing the error message in Excel can be suppressed by adding a environment system variable VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS=1). One last note:  Me.Application.Quit closes all instances of Excel, so it's probably not safe to use.